# I can't get my switch function to work

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Question is to sum up all values of 1 to 10, inclusive, excluding the values 3 and 6, however I have no idea why my switch function is not filtering out 3 and 6.
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a=1,total=0;

    while (a<=10)
    {
        a++;

        switch (a)
        {
            case 3:
                continue;
            case 6:
                continue;
            default:
                total = total + a;
        }
    }

    cout << "Sum of the total numbers are " << total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. it should. Btw, why don't you use a for loop? That would make it less error prone: You are summing up 2..11! Plus to continue from inside the switch is not very idiomatic, a break (to exit the switch) would be more common.

Comment: My out put was 56. Which is the sum of the numbers between 2 and 11 inclusive, excluding 3 and 6. I think you're just confused by the fact that a actually goes to 11 and starts at 2.

Comment: When you get answers you don't expect, don't make assumptions about why the answer is wrong if you're going to ask help with that assumption! The 3 and 6 are skipped as you intend, but as @PeterSchneider states, your list of values is 2...11, not 1...10.

Comment: in the default-clause, add `cout<<"adding"<<a<<endl;` and you'll see the error

Comment: Why not use some maths any remove the loop. i.e. total or 1 to n is equal to `n * (n +1) / 2`. Then knock off the ones you are not interest in.

Comment: @EdHeal I think it's probably safe to assume the point here isn't to get the sum of `1 .. 10` but rather to learn how to use some construct in C++ (perhaps in this case, loops in general).

Comment: Ok, I changed the initial value of a=1 to a=0, and instead i get my sum as 57 now. hmmm, i appreciate all of your advices :) 

and this is a question from a textbook, textbook says to use a while loop, so im using a while loop/

Comment: @MrDuk - Does the institution that the person teach mathematics alongside computing? Perhaps extra credit would be due to provide both solutions along with a critque with what one is the best

Answer (score 3):

If you add the following to the end of your while loop:

```
cout << "Current total: " << total << " a=" << a << endl;
```

it will become clear what the issue is. Your output will look like this:

```
Current total: 2 a=2
Current total: 6 a=4
Current total: 11 a=5
Current total: 18 a=7
Current total: 26 a=8
Current total: 35 a=9
Current total: 45 a=10
Current total: 56 a=11
Sum of the total numbers are 56
```

As you can see, it's correctly skipping 3 and 6, but it's missing 1 and is adding 11, which are two things I don't think you were expecting.

Also, you're using `continue`. With a switch statement, you want to use `break` to keep from executing the cases after the current one. (To elaborate on this a bit, I think `continue` would have been fine because I think it was doing what you wanted: transferring control back to the while statement. This won't work if the `a++` is moved after the switch statement, however. If you start `a` at `0`, change your condition to `a < 10` as mentioned in the other post, then you could use the `continue` statements instead of the `break`)

If you move `a++;` to the end of your while loop and fix the `continue` statements, I believe it will work as you expect.

Worried my edits might confuse the matter, here are two alternate ways you can structure the code to get the result you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a=1,total=0;
    while (a<=10)
    {
        switch (a)
        {
            case 3:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            default:
                total = total + a;
        }
        a++;
    }
    cout << "Sum of the total numbers are " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a=0,total=0;
    while (a<10)
    {
        a++;
        switch (a)
        {
            case 3:
                continue;
            case 6:
                continue;
            default:
                total = total + a;
        }
    }
    cout << "Sum of the total numbers are " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly, you only make minor mistakes in your central loop: a goes from 2 to 11 instead of from 1 to 10. it should be like this:

```
int a=0, total=0;

while (a < 10)
{
    a++;

    // rest of code
}
```

**EDIT** so my answer is more complete. The fix above will get your code working so it produces the correct results, but as @Pete noted, `continue` is not the way to get out of a switch case statement. Your `continue` statement directly moves you back to the next loop of your `while` loop. A better and cleaner code would be like this:

```
int a=0,total=0;

while (a < 10)
{
    a++;
    switch (a)
    {
        case 3:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        default:
            total = total + a;
    }
    // in every case you will get here; even if a==3 or a==6
}
```

**EDIT2**
if you prefer to let a loop from 1 to 10, this is possible as well:

```
int a=1,total=0;

while (a <= 10)
{
    switch (a)
    {
        case 3:
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
        default:
            total = total + a;
    }
    // in every case you will get here; even if a==3 or a==6
    a++;
}
```

Comment: better (first bracket indentation disturbed me), now you get a +1 :-)

Comment: if it's a<10, wouldn't the loop stop at a=9 only?

Comment: @user3499156 yes indeed; it would go into that loop one last time when a=9. The first command in the loop is: "a++"; thus a will become 10...

Comment: @ChrisMaes ahhh, pranked by my own codes. I will take notice of where I put my increment next time.

Comment: @user3499156 going from 0 to 9 is very common in c/c++ code. However if you prefer to loop from 1 to 10 that is possible... I'll add that in my answer... If you are satisfied with one of the answers; you can accept that answer...